# System.AccessViolationException - Update table with TableAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, access-violation, tableadapter

I can't update my Tabel. I have weird bug. This is part of my code where I call table adapter of table which I want to update.

```
        int iD = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
        string name = txtName.Text;
        string des = richTxtDes.Text;
        int idCategory = Convert.ToInt32(cmbCategory.SelectedValue.ToString());
        int idSupp = Convert.ToInt32(cmbSupp.SelectedValue.ToString());
        string manufacutere = txtManufacture.Text;
        string commentar= richTxtComm.Text;

        MagacinDataSetTableAdapters.InventoryTableAdapter inventariTableAdapter = new MagacinDataSetTableAdapters.InventoryTableAdapter();
        inventariTableAdapter.UpdateInventoryQuery(name,des,idCategory,idSupp,manufacutre,commentar,iD); //Here is a bug

        loadInventory();//Update dataGridView
```

Here is a SQL for Table Update: UPDATE `Inventory` SET `ItemName` = ?, `Description` = ?, `CategoryID` = ?, `SupplierID` = ?, `Manufacturer` = ?, 
`Comments` = ? WHERE `ID` = ?

Picture of error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried to find some solution online but without success. And then I tried to create new Access Database with the same tables like older. I replaced older DB with the same new DB and my code work. Problem is in DB, I used some DB which I found on internet, it's few years old. Now with new DB my program work very well. Interesting this is that only this table had a problem.